# What kind of collection to use in grails controller?

Tags: list, grails, collections, groovy, controller

I have data being pulled out from the web. I have managed to put the fields I need in variables. How would I put them in a collection? Should I use expandos? I do not have model class. I am thinking about using a collection of some sort and then print them out in my GSP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Expando's is possible, but not recommended. Maps ([:]) provide the same amount of functionality and are generally easier to use. Also, I'd consider it a really bad practice to use only collections, in this case Maps, to transfer the data, unless it's either a) a tiny bit of data, or the b) the data is unstructured, and not easily put into a model.

Personally, I would just create the class to hold the data. Easier to talk about, and easier to maintain.

An example:

```
class Result {
    String name
    String value
}
```

Which you would use in your controllers actions like:

```
def oneResult() {
     return [result:new Result(name:'my name', value: 'my value')]
}
```

or

```
def manyResults() {
     return [result:[ 
          new Result(name:'my name1', value: 'my value1'),
          new Result(name:'my name2', value: 'my value2'),
          new Result(name:'my name3', value: 'my value3')
     ]]
}
```

Both of them would return a model which can be referenced using the 'result' name in your GSP page, and you can use a  or  to loop over the contents of the result.

Comment: I went with your suggestion and created a model class, so I now should just basically add the data from my controller to the class right?

Comment: Agree on Expando behavior but I somehow do not feel `groovier` to use DTOs only to pass model from `controller` to `view`. I think it is an anti-pattern now in terms of groovy and against DRY. On the other hand, you have a [DTO plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/dto) which you can use and would also like to refer to [Peter's post](http://www.cacoethes.co.uk/blog/groovyandgrails/introduction-to-the-dto-plugin).

Comment: I agree with you to use DTO's. Not sure why you'd call this an antipattern though; I think it's the easiest way to get data out of a system. And maybe I misunderstood the question. I read 'use a collection and print them in a GSP'. Not really sure what 'data pulled out from the web' means :).

Comment: Yes exactly, DTOs can be helpful if serialized and sent over a network in a RMI call. I guess we both attacked the question in different perspectives and ended with fruitful results. :)

Comment: For some reason my model class is not getting read in my controller?Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, so maybe it's better to create a new question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Groovy Maps](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps). 
`[foo1: bar1, foo2: bar2, .....]`

Expandos are useful for creating dynamic objects.

```
def myExpando = new Expando()
myExpando.name = "Test User"
myExpando.app = "Grails" 
myExpando.task = { 
     "Hello, $name. Have you read the $app docs yet?" 
}

println myExpando.task()
myExpando.app = "Groovy"
println myExpando.task()
```

Output:

```
Hello, Test User. Have you read the Grails docs yet?
Hello, Test User. Have you read the Groovy docs yet?
```

If you need the above dynamic property in the view layer you can use Expando.

Comment: Lets say i have name, status code and email that I need to display in my gsp page. I could basically then say, myExpando.name= varName

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by someone in this site, I ended up using something like

```
def List = []

//Grabbed everything i needed here and then added to the List

 List << ["Id": Id,"Name":Name]

//Return the list
```